# how to pass second params as ' ' without suffix and prefix in i18n on reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, variables, parameters, i18next

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import detector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import translationEn from '~/lang/data/translation_en.json';
import translationKo from '~/lang/data/translation_ko.json';

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: translationEn,
  },
  ko: {
    translation: translationKo,
  },
};

i18n
  .use(detector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    react: {
      transEmptyNodeValue: '!null',
      transSupportBasicHtmlNodes: true,
      transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor: ['br', 'strong', 'i'],
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

```
{"data_to_transfer": "Saving data to transfer to {{test.data}}"}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 const test = {
    data: 'PC',
  };
 <p className='para'>{t('data_to_transfer'),'test'}</p>
```

I'd like to pass the second params like this

{t('data_to_transfer'),'test'}

but every documentation only explaining like below..

{t('data_to_transfer'),{{test.data}}}

plz gimme advice abt this

Answer (score 0):

It's the second argument of the t function:

```
<p className='para'>{t('data_to_transfer', { test: { data: 'my data' } })}</p>
```

Check out this crash course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SA_9i4TtxLQ&t=433s

Comment: I mean like I'd like to pass the second argument the type of this <p className='para'>{ t ( 'data_to_transfer', 'data' ) }</p> hmmm... not use with curly brackets w them.{ test: { data: 'my data' } }

Comment: The i18next t call interface works like I described